# Typescript export aggregator

Tags: typescript

Basically I'm trying to aggregate imports under a namespace and re-export them.

For example: If I have 3 files A,B,C I want to do something like this

```
export module A.something {
    export * from A;
}
export module B.something {
    export * from B;
}
export module C.something {
    export * from C;
}
```

When I try importing them this way the module `A.something` exists but doesn't contain an any exports.

Answer (score 0):

A way of doing it can be importing everything into the **aggregator.ts** and exporting it back out in a single object:

```js
import * as A from './A';
import * as B from './B';

export { A, B };
```

And you could later use it as such:

```js
import { A } from './aggregate';

let something = new A.AClass();
```

Comment: This works but my module names I want to export under are nested. This seems to only work when exporting under a single name. Can I do something similar but `export * as A.b.c from './A';`